# How do I convert from Cartesian to spherical coordinates?

Tags: opengl, glsl, coordinates

This seems like a fairly basic and common problem. Is there a builtin way to achieve it or do I have to write the algorithm on my own? If I do, how should it work?

Comment: @Anko Your edit pretty much changes the objective of the question^^ But it is probably better for future reference...

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm aware of (you're asking if there's some sort of glsl function that would do the conversion, right?)

It's a pretty simple conversion though, just three lines; here it is in pseudocode:

```
r = sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
theta = atan2(y,x);
phi = atan2(sqrt(x*x+y*y),z);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but one has to sort out the case when x is zero if I read the spec of atan() correctly. I just thought, people must be doing this all the time, so a builtin function might be available.

Comment: x being 0 shouldn't be a problem, you'd only have issues with the above if r = 0       https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: According to https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/atan.xhtml atan(y,x) is undefined whenever x is zero.

Comment: Oh crap... it looks like there isn't an atan2 function in glsl after all, my bad.  Out of curiosity, what are you using the spherical coordinates for?  Do they get plugged into other trig functions after you've converted them?

Comment: Well the glsl atan() with 2 args works just like atan2(). I am building an app that displays certain aspects of the wave function of a hydrogen atom (and I am teaching myself OpenGL).

Comment: Man, now that I'm taking a second look at the documentation you linked, it's weird- they say that atan(y_over_x) gives a full 2pi radian range of return, while the overloaded two argument version only gives half that range, but you'd expect it to be the reverse (with most math libraries atan will return with pi/2 and -pi/2 while atan2 will return between pi and -pi).  I wonder if the overloaded atan with two arguments actually works like the atan2 described in the wikipedia article I linked, and someone fudged the glsl documentation?  What happens if you try atan(1,0)? Does it return pi/2?

Comment: You just read it the wrong way around ;)

Comment: Haha crap, you're right!  I gotta get some sleep :P   I just found a thread where someone was wondering about the atan issue and he posted a way to get around it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070410/robust-atany-x-on-glsl-for-converting-xy-coordinate-to-angle

Answer (score 1):

This did not helpe me achieve a full sphere coordinate conversions, I always got all my coordinates for a sphere in only half the sphere whether using atan with one parameter (atan(y/x)) or with two (atan(y, x)).

Here's what worked for me. I based the calculations on the formulas in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system .

In this example vertex shader, the radius is distorted based upon phi and theta.

```
const float PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749;

float getPhi(in float y, in float x)
{
    if (x == 0.0) {
        if (y == 0.0) {
            return 0.0;
        } else if (y > 0.0) {
            return PI/2.0;
        } else {
            return -1.0 * PI/2.0;
        }
    } else if (x > 0.0) {
        return atan(y/x);
    } else if (x < 0.0) {
        if (y >= 0.0) {
            return atan(y/x) + PI;
        } else {
            return atan(y/x) + PI;
        }
    }
}

vec3 toPolar(in vec3 cart)
{
    float xySquared = (cart.x * cart.x) + (cart.y * cart.y);
    float radius = sqrt(xySquared + (cart.z * cart.z));
    return vec3(radius, atan(sqrt(xySquared), cart.z), getPhi(cart.y, cart.x));
}

vec3 toCartesian(in vec3 sph) {
    return vec3(
        sin(sph.y) * cos(sph.z) * sph.x,
        sin(sph.y) * sin(sph.z) * sph.x,
        cos(sph.y) * sph.x
    );
}


void main()
{
    float disp = 2.0;
    vec3 sphericalPt = toPolar(position);

    vec3 sphericalDisp = vec3(
        sphericalPt.x + sin(position.x * 2.0 + position.y * 5.0 + position.z * 12.0 ) * disp,
        sphericalPt.y,
        sphericalPt.z
    );

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(toCartesian(sphericalDisp), 1.0);
}
```